# Multipeer Connectivity Connecting / Managing Peers Manually

Tags: ios, swift, multipeer-connectivity

I am trying to figure out what the NSData object is to connect to a peer manually. I can't find it in the apple documentation, all it says is that it needs the connection data object from the peer but I cant find where I get that from. Here is the [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MCSessionClassRef/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MCSession/nearbyConnectionDataForPeer:withCompletionHandler:)

I want to use this

```
 func connectPeer(_ peerID: MCPeerID!, withNearbyConnectionData data: NSData!)
```

I am using this method when a peer disconnects. For some reason when a peer disconnects I can still send and receive information from it so I want to force the reconnection with this method.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Any reason you want to do it this way, rather than using the higher-level `MCNearbyServiceBrowser` and `MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser` classes?

Comment: all I can see you can do to force the connection is to re-invite them to the session using the browser. I am having big issues with dropped connections even though I can still send and receive messages.

Comment: Can you post the code that you're currently getting dropped connections with? MPC has several known issues and you may just be experiencing one of them.

Comment: @ChrisH it's not really specific code that I am getting dropped connections it more the situation. It is also that sometimes one device might not find all the other devices around it. That way if I got an answer to what the Data needs to be for  `func connectPeer(_ peerID: MCPeerID!, withNearbyConnectionData data: NSData!)` I can work around some of these issues.

Comment: Makes sense. I've added a potential answer

Answer (score 2):

The `NSData` object you are looking for is part of this function's completion block:

```
func nearbyConnectionDataForPeer(_ peerID: MCPeerID!,
       withCompletionHandler completionHandler: ((NSData!,
                                      NSError!) -> Void)!)
```

It's not clear from the documentation, but I suspect your own discovery code would pass your locally created `MCPeerID` object to other discovered devices during the initial connection phase. Then you'd use the discovered peer's `MCPeerID` object in the above function, and finally call the `connectPeer` function with the data you get back.

I'd be interested to hear if you ever get this working!

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to know about data which is passed to peers to establish connection, I sugest you should go through this documet:
[truth about multipeer connectivity framework](https://www.blackhat.com/docs/us-14/materials/us-14-Diquet-It-Just-Networks-The-Truth-About-iOS-7s-Multipeer-Connectivity-Framework.pdf)